# Помогите разобраться с замедлением многопоточной (c++ threads) реализацией игры "Жизнь"

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, parallel

Делая задание по реализации игры "Жизнь" Конвея, столкнулся с непонятной мне проблемой. Ниже приведен листинг части программы.

```
std::vector< std::thread > threads;
unsigned int NUM_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
std::cout << std::endl << "Avaliable threads: " << NUM_THREADS << std::endl;
std::cout << "C++ threads programm starts to work..." << std::endl;

std::vector<unsigned int> changes(NUM_THREADS, 0);
std::vector<unsigned int> borders;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
    borders.push_back(i * field_height / NUM_THREADS);
borders.push_back(field_height);
threads.reserve(NUM_THREADS);
t1 = GetTickCount();
do
{
    std::fill(changes.begin(), changes.end(), 0);
    isChange = 0;
    {
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < NUM_THREADS; ++k) {
            threads.emplace_back(
                [&borders, &changes, k, flag]() {
                //std::cerr << borders[k] << " - " << borders[k + 1] << std::endl;
                    for (unsigned int i = borders[k]; i < borders[k + 1]; ++i)
                    {
                        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < field_width; ++j)
                        {
                            changes[k] += changeNeibours(flag, i, j, changes[k]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        for (auto &thread : threads) {
            thread.join();
        }
        threads.clear();
    }
    if (flag == 0) 
        flag++;
    else 
        flag--;
    toCount++;
    for (auto change : changes)
        isChange += change;
    if (isChange == 0 && isSteady())
    {
        std::cout << "Steady state reached!" << std::endl;
        break;
    }
} while (toCount != generations);
t2 = GetTickCount();
parallel_time = t2 - t1;
std::cout << "C++ threads programm time: " << (double)parallel_time / 1000 << " seconds" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Amount of iterations done: " << iter << std::endl;
if (parallel_time)
    std::cout << "Acceleration: " << (double)consistent_time / parallel_time << std::endl;
```

Поле замкнуто в тор. Функция **changeNeibours** проверяет соседей и записывает результат проверки. На каждом итерации мира (в каждом поколении) одна матрица является текущим поколением (только читается для проверки), другая - будущим (только записывается результат проверки каждой ячейки), они смсеняются по изменению переменной **flag**. Вектор **changes** содержит информацию о количестве изменений состояния клеток в каждом потоке, после завершения просчета нового поколения они складываются и проверяется на достижение стационарного состояния.

Программа работает функционально правильно, то есть расчет N поколений проходит верно (проверял, сравнивая со сторонними реализациями и просчетом на бумажке). Последовательная реализация (полный код программы приложен) отрабатывает также верно и показывает аналогичный результат.
Проблема заключается в том что на процессоре Intel Core i5 6600K, используя 4 потока, параллельная реализация работает в 23 раза медленнее, нежели последовательная при одинаковых входных данных:

- Размер поля 100х100
- Количество поколений 100000
- В поле добавляется фигура Blinker для избежания стационарного состояния
- Число потоков 4

При изменении входных данных на:

- Размер поля 10000х10000
- Количество поколений 5
- В поле добавляется фигура Blinker для избежания стационарного состояния
- Число потоков 4

Праллельная реализация замедляется всего в 2 раза. Для наглядности приведу скриншоты моих замеров.

[image: замер первой ситуации]
[image: замер второй ситуации]

Вопрос заключается в том, что я написал такого, что программа так сильно замедляется в параллельном исполнении.

На всякий случай приведу полный код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

int checkBorders(int index, int size);
void printField(int flag, std::string name);
int changeNeibours(int flag, int i, int j, int isChange);
bool isSteady();
void randomStartFilling();
void startFilling();


const unsigned int field_width = 10000;
const unsigned int field_height = 10000;
const unsigned int generations = 5;

bool fields[field_width][field_height];
bool new_fields[field_width][field_height];
bool fields2[field_width][field_height];
bool new_fields2[field_width][field_height];
bool temp_fields[field_width][field_height];

/*
* FUNCTION FOR CHECKING BORDERS
*/
int checkBorders(int index, int size)
{
    int result;
    if (index == -1)
    {
        result = size - 1;
        return result;
    }
    if (index == size)
    {
        result = 0;
        return result;
    }
    return index;
}

/*
* FUNCTION FOR CHECKING NEIGHBOURS
*/
int changeNeibours(int flag, int i, int j, int isChange)
{
    int neib = 0;
    switch (flag)
    {
    case 0: {
        if (fields[checkBorders(i + 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j - 1, field_width)] == 1) //down left
            neib++;
        if (fields[checkBorders(i + 1, field_height)][j] == 1) //down
            neib++;
        if (fields[checkBorders(i + 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j + 1, field_width)] == 1) //down right
            neib++;
        if (fields[checkBorders(i - 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j - 1, field_width)] == 1) //up left
            neib++;
        if (fields[checkBorders(i - 1, field_height)][j] == 1) //up
            neib++;
        if (fields[checkBorders(i - 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j + 1, field_width)] == 1) //up right
            neib++;
        if (fields[i][checkBorders(j - 1, field_width)] == 1) //left
            neib++;
        if (fields[i][checkBorders(j + 1, field_width)] == 1) //right
            neib++;
        if (fields[i][j] == 0)
        {
            if (neib == 3)
            {
                new_fields[i][j] = 1;
                isChange++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((neib < 2) || (neib > 3))
            {
                new_fields[i][j] = 0;
                isChange++;
            }
        }
    }
            break;
    case 1: {
        if (new_fields[checkBorders(i + 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j - 1, field_width)] == 1) //down left
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[checkBorders(i + 1, field_height)][j] == 1) //down
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[checkBorders(i + 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j + 1, field_width)] == 1) //down right
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[checkBorders(i - 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j - 1, field_width)] == 1) //up left
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[checkBorders(i - 1, field_height)][j] == 1) //up
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[checkBorders(i - 1, field_height)][checkBorders(j + 1, field_width)] == 1) //up right
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[i][checkBorders(j - 1, field_width)] == 1) //left
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[i][checkBorders(j + 1, field_width)] == 1) //right
            neib++;
        if (new_fields[i][j] == 0)
        {
            if (neib == 3)
            {
                fields[i][j] = 1;
                isChange++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ((neib < 2) || (neib > 3))
            {
                fields[i][j] = 0;
                isChange++;
            }
        }
    }
            break;
    }
    return isChange;
}

/*
* FUNCTION FOR PRINTING FIELD
*/
void printField(int flag, std::string name) {
    std::fstream f;
    f.open(name + ".txt", std::ios::out);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < field_height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < field_width; ++j) {
            if (flag)
                f << fields[i][j];
            else
                f << new_fields[i][j];
        }
        f << std::endl;
    }
}

/*
* FUNCTION FOR CHECKING FOR STEADY STATE
*/
bool isSteady() {
    for (int i = 0; i < field_height; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < field_width; ++j) {
            if (fields[i][j] != new_fields[i][j])
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/*
* FUNCTION FOR RANDOM FILLING START WORLD
*/
void randomStartFilling() {
    for (int i = 0; i < field_width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < field_height; j++)
        {
            fields[i][j] = rand() % 2 + 0;
            temp_fields[i][j] = fields[i][j];
            new_fields[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

/*
* FUNCTION FOR FILLING START WORLD WITH FLICKER
*/
void startFilling() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 || i == 2)
                fields[i][j] = 0;
            else
                fields[i][j] = 1;
            temp_fields[i][j] = fields[i][j];
            new_fields[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 3; i < field_width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 3; j < field_height; j++)
        {
            fields[i][j] = rand() % 2 + 0;
            temp_fields[i][j] = fields[i][j];
            new_fields[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

/*
* MAIN
*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int isChange;
    int toCount;
    int flag = 0;
    long t1 = 0;
    long t2 = 0;
    long consistent_time = 0, parallel_time = 0;
    int iter = 0;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    //randomStartFilling();
    startFilling();

    /*
    * BEGIN OF CONSISTENT PART
    */
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Amount of generations to calculate: " << generations << std::endl;
    std::cout << "World size: " << field_width << "x" << field_height << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Amount of iterations to be done: " << generations * field_width * field_height << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Consistent programm starts to work..." << std::endl;

    toCount = 0;
    t1 = GetTickCount();
    do
    {
        isChange = 0;
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < field_height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < field_width; j++)
                {
                    isChange += changeNeibours(flag, i, j, isChange);
                    ++iter;
                }
            }
        }
        if (flag == 0) flag++;
        else flag--;
        toCount++;
        if (isChange == 0 && isSteady())
        {
            std::cout << "Steady state reached!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (toCount != generations);
    t2 = GetTickCount();
    consistent_time = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << "Consistent programm time: " << (double)consistent_time / 1000 << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Amount of iterations done: " << iter << std::endl;

    //printField(flag, "consistent");

    /*
    * END OF CONSISTENT PART
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < field_height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < field_width; j++)
        {
            fields2[i][j] = fields[i][j];
            fields[i][j] = temp_fields[i][j];
            new_fields[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    flag = 0;
    toCount = 0;
    iter = 0;

    /*
    * BEGIN OF C++ threads PART
    */

    std::vector< std::thread > threads;
    unsigned int NUM_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    //NUM_THREADS = 2;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Avaliable threads: " << NUM_THREADS << std::endl;
    std::cout << "C++ threads programm starts to work..." << std::endl;

    std::vector<unsigned int> iterations(NUM_THREADS, 0);
    std::vector<unsigned int> changes(NUM_THREADS, 0);
    std::vector<unsigned int> borders;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i)
        borders.push_back(i * field_height / NUM_THREADS);
    borders.push_back(field_height);
    threads.reserve(NUM_THREADS);
    t1 = GetTickCount();
    do
    {
        std::fill(changes.begin(), changes.end(), 0);
        std::fill(iterations.begin(), iterations.end(), 0);
        isChange = 0;
        {
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < NUM_THREADS; ++k) {
                threads.emplace_back(
                    [&borders, &changes, &iterations, k, flag]() {
                    //std::cerr << borders[k] << " - " << borders[k + 1] << std::endl;
                        for (unsigned int i = borders[k]; i < borders[k + 1]; ++i)
                        {
                            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < field_width; ++j)
                            {
                                changes[k] += changeNeibours(flag, i, j, changes[k]);
                                ++iterations[k];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            for (auto &thread : threads) {
                thread.join();
            }
            threads.clear();
        }
        if (flag == 0) 
            flag++;
        else 
            flag--;
        toCount++;
        for (auto iteration : iterations)
            iter += iteration;
        for (auto change : changes)
            isChange += change;
        if (isChange == 0 && isSteady())
        {
            std::cout << "Steady state reached!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (toCount != generations);
    t2 = GetTickCount();
    parallel_time = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << "C++ threads programm time: " << (double)parallel_time / 1000 << " seconds" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Amount of iterations done: " << iter << std::endl;
    if (parallel_time)
        std::cout << "Acceleration: " << (double)consistent_time / parallel_time << std::endl;

    //printField(flag, "cppThreads");

    /*
    * END OF C++ threads PART
    */
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Посоветую воспользоваться профилировщиком, например gprof для выяснения на что же уходит так много времени

Comment: А эти результаты были получены в релизной версии?

Comment: @VTT Да релиз х64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что бросается в глаза - это создание и уничтожение потоков на каждой итерации. Создавайте все потоки при старте программы.

Далее, при каждом вычислении все потоки пишут и читают элементы в массивах `changes` и `iterations`. Несмотря на то, что они не конфликтуют между собой и обращаются исключительно к элементу, соответствующему индексу потока, это все равно приводит к резкому замедлению работы. Дело в том, что эти массивы имеют маленький размер и помещаются в одну (или пару соседних) кэш-линий. Соответственно при изменении **любого** элемента будет производится процедура синхронизации всей кэш линии на всех ядрах. Для устранения этой проблемы нужно улучшить локальность данных, например сделать локальные переменные-счетчики и записывать их финальное значение в общий массив при окончании итерации:

```
unsigned int rows_start{borders[k]};
unsigned int rows_end{borders[k + 1]};
unsigned long long changes_count{};
unsigned long long iterations_count{};
for(unsigned int row_index{rows_start}; row_index < rows_end; ++row_index)
{
    for (unsigned int col_index{}; col_index < field_width; ++col_index)
    {
        changes_count = changeNeibours(flag, row_index, col_index, changes_count);
        ++iterations_count;
    }
}
changes[k] = changes_count;
iterations[k] = iterations_count;
```

В таком варианте второй тест дает практически линейное увеличение производительности с увеличением количества потоков.

Comment: Почему тогда замедление наблюдается и при минимальном колличестве итераций, но увеличенном размере поля?

Comment: Возможно я не понимаю, но где возникает, на ваш взгляд, состояние гонки, если на каждой итерации один массив только читается, другой только изменяется? Может ли это быть при проверке соседей, то есть возможном чтении из одних и тех же ячеек одного массива? Если последнее верно, как можно это обойти, может быть передавать массивы как локальные копии в потоки?

Comment: @lolmosk `changeNeibours` как-то странно написана, там из-за копипасты представляется, что оба поля могут изменяться.

Comment: и можете, пожалуйста, объяснить как после операции **join()** не уничтожая поток дать ему задание новое или дать ссылку на какой-либо ресурасс, везде нахожу примеры с одноразовым использованием потоков.

Comment: И если не очень сложно, то ресурсы, чтобы понять и максимально просто реализовать тоже самое задание с использованием AVX инструкций, openCL, MPI и POSIX, буду изучать.

Comment: @lolmosk Дополнил ответ. Что касается других вопросов, то вам лучше создать для них отдельный топик.